# hive query with counts

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

We have a Hive Table like below:

[image: Hive Table]

We would like to see output like below:

[image: Output]

For each date, display the counts of customer who bought each fruit. if no one bought a fruit for that day, replace it with 0 in place of NULL. any Apache Query to achieve this is highly appreciated

Update: 
There will only be four products Apples, Bananas, Grapes and Oranges. we would not want to find distinct dates and distinct products.

Answer (score 1):

If your RDMS supports `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`, that's a simple aggregate query:

```
SELECT mydate, product, COUNT(DISTINCT customer)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY mydate, product
```

PS : it is usually not a good idea to name a column `date`, as this conflicts with the homonym sql datatype. I changed it to `mydate` in the queries.

---

Without `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`, you would need to use a subquery:

```
SELECT mydate, product, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT mydate, product, customer FROM mytable) x
GROUP BY mydate, product
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `cross join` to generate the rows and then `left join` and `group by` for the calcualtion:

```
select d.date, p.product, count(t.date) 
from (select distinct date from t) d cross join
     (select distinct product from t) p left join
     t
     on t.date = d.date and t.product = p.product
group by d.date, p.product
order by d.date, p.product;
```

The hint that you need `cross join` is that some of the returned counts are `0`, so data combinations not in the original data need to be "generated".

Comment: Hi, Thank you. Update: 
There will only be four products Apples, Bananas, Grapes and Oranges. we would not want to find distinct dates and distinct products.